# Unable to open vim in terminal ide app for android

Tags: vim, java, android, terminal-emulator, application

I have installed terminal ide app for android. I intend to develop java applications in android tablet. Vi text editor is working fine. But I find it difficult to use. I am comfortable with Vim. But Vim is having trouble opening in the app. It gives me the following error.

```
"vim": error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.
Aborted.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Report this to the authors of the app, what else.

Comment: Vim probably needs to be recompiled against API 16 SDK in order to work with Android 5 (Lollipop) and above. Not sure how to do that myself though.